# How to get list of loaded application classes in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

Let's say that I have an application deployed to Tomcat. Ideally, I want to be able to undeploy said application without stopping my server and all classes that belong to the application should be cleanly unloaded from Tomcat.

But, it may happen that I've created some object somewhere that's preventing all classes from being unloaded. Is there a mechanism to list loaded classes so I can check if the application is being unloaded (undeployed) cleanly or not?

I'm aware of Tomcat's JMX interface but I haven't found any of the information I'm looking for in that.

Comment: Step 1) log into admin console. Step 2) click undeploy. Step 3) click "check for memory leaks".

Comment: @BoristheSpider Note that this "check for memory leaks" feature only tells you if something is wrong. It doesn't really help you diagnose the source of the problem. You need to do actual work for that :)

Comment: @BoristheSpider Do you happen to know what to do to get which classes have been leaked?

Comment: It’s not classes, it’s _threads_. Or threadlocals on server threads. And I think it tells you that.

Comment: I can monitor threads easy enough with JMX and there's even a log entry generated if a thread stays after an application is unloaded. What about ThreadLocal? I don't have enough experience with those.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to undeploy said application without stopping my
>   server ...

Use the Admin Console also known as Tomcat Web Application Manager. It does exactly what you need: Stops particular application, unloads all its classes. Open URL `your_host:port/manager/html`.

Comment: I know how to undeploy an application. I want to be able to figure out (in dev env) if any objects are being left behind after unloading the application.

Comment: Shouldnt be, its loaded using separate classloader

Comment: When application is stopped, there can be no object in the memory related to this application. The easiest way to check it is to use a profiler like VisualVM. The more complex way is to use instrumentation API and to implement a Java agent.

Comment: @mentallurg false. In a servlet container environment applications can leak memory - and most do. References held by the container prevent unloading of the application classloader which in turn hold the whole lot in memory. A classic example being leaked thread locals - because the servlet container controls the thread.

Comment: If your application isn't undeploying cleanly, it's up to you to fix the application. Have a look at [Tomcat's presentations page](http://tomcat.apache.org/presentations.html), specifically at the one currently listed at the bottom of the page titled "Memory Leaks".